# Filter each column with a different condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working on filtering a data frame using *dplyr*. The problem is that the predicates differs between columns.

Please find below a minimal example with three columns and three predicates:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
dframe <- rerun(3, rnorm(5)) %>%
  set_names(paste0("var", 1:3)) %>% 
  data.frame

cond <- c(2, 1, -1.4)
dframe %>% filter(var1 < cond[1] & var2 < cond[2] & var3 > cond[3])
```

Is there any way to filter the data set without explicitly stating the predicates in `filter`?

**Edit:** A potential solution to the problem is obviously using a for-loop, see the code below. However, there might be more elegant solutions.

```
dframe_help <- dframe
cond <- c(2, 1, -1.4)
isSmaller <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
for(i in seq_along(cond)) {
  if (isSmaller[i])
    dframe_help <- dframe_help %>% filter_at(.vars = vars(num_range(prefix = "var", range = i)), 
                                             .vars_predicate = all_vars(. < cond[i]))
  else
    dframe_help <- dframe_help %>% filter_at(.vars = vars(num_range(prefix = "var", range = i)), 
                                            .vars_predicate = all_vars(. > cond[i]))
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "predicate"? A column? What's wrong your code example?

Comment: With predicate I mean (var1 < cond[1]).
My code cannot be automatized, i.e., when the number of variables increases, the code become were confusing.

Comment: Ok, so you mean a logical statement. I'm still not sure what you like to do. You want to `filter` rows *without* explicitly stating the/any logical statement(s)? But then what are the conditions according to which you select rows? Perhaps you need to give more context as to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some sort of object to specify whether to use `<` or `>`. I've created one called `less`, which is `1` for `<` and 0 for `>`.

```
require(purrr); require(magrittr)
filter2 <- function(dframe, cond, less){
            rows <- pmap(list(cond, less, dframe), 
                         function(cond, less, x) if(less) x < cond else x > cond
                         ) %>% 
                        pmap_lgl(all)
            dframe[rows,]
}

dframe %>% filter2(cond = c(2, 1, -1.4), less = c(1, 1, 0))
```

Or, explicitly pass the function you want to use for each variable.

```
filter3 <- function(df, y, fun){
        df[pmap(list(df, y, fun), function(x, y, fun) fun(x, y)) %>% 
                pmap_lgl(all)
        ,]
}


dframe %>% filter3(y = c(2, 1, -1.4), fun = list(`<`, `<`, `>`))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by 'automating' this process, but here are a couple of options.

If you want to filter along multiple features with some extra clarity, you can create a standalone filtering function:

```
cond <- c(2, 1, -1.4)
filter_using_conditions <- function(df) {
  df[df$var1 < cond[1] & df$var2 < cond[2] & df$var3 > cond[3],]
}
dframe %>%
  filter_using_conditions()
        var1       var2       var3
2  0.4978505 -0.2179749  0.8377870
3 -1.9666172 -1.0260044  0.1533731
4  0.7013559 -0.7288912 -1.1381369
5 -0.4727914 -0.6250393  1.2538149
```

If you want implement a solution using vectors of operators and values, you can try doing some string manipulation and use `base::eval()` or `glue::eval()` to generate a logical vector for subsetting your dataframe. Here's an example using `purrr:map` and `purrr:map2` (it's not very elegant but hopefully gets the point across):

```
cond <- c(2, 1, -1.4)
operators <- c("<", "<", ">")

filter_conditions <- function(dframe, conds, operators) {
  x <- paste(operators, conds, sep = " ")
  rows_to_use <- map2(dframe, x, paste) %>%
    map(map_lgl, glue::evaluate, NULL) %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    na_if(FALSE) %>%
    complete.cases()
  dframe[rows_to_use,]
}
filter_conditions(dframe, cond, operators)
        var1       var2       var3
2  0.4978505 -0.2179749  0.8377870
3 -1.9666172 -1.0260044  0.1533731
4  0.7013559 -0.7288912 -1.1381369
5 -0.4727914 -0.6250393  1.2538149
```

This example uses `purrr:map2()` to generate individual strings for each datapoint using the specified operator-condition pairings, and then uses `glue::evaluate()` and `purrr:map2()` to execute those strings as commands and return logical vectors. `dplyr::na_if()` is used so you can later use `complete.cases()` to get a logical vector corresponding to row indices.

```
map2(dframe, x, paste)
$var1
[1] "1.78691313680308 < 2"   "0.497850478229239 < 2"  "-1.96661715662964 < 2"  "0.701355901563686 < 2" 
[5] "-0.472791407727934 < 2"

$var2
[1] "-1.06782370598685 < 1"  "-0.217974914658295 < 1" "-1.02600444830724 < 1"  "-0.72889122929114 < 1" 
[5] "-0.625039267849257 < 1"

$var3
[1] "-1.68669331074241 > -1.4" "0.837787044494525 > -1.4" "0.153373117836515 > -1.4"
[4] "-1.13813693701195 > -1.4" "1.25381492106993 > -1.4"
```